# Traces of Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

**Is there a simple proof of the following fact?**

> **Theorem.** *Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded and smooth domain.  If $n>2$, then    $W^{1,n-1}(\partial\Omega)\subset
> W^{1-\frac{1}{n},n}(\partial\Omega)$.   That is, there is a bounded
>   extension operator  ${\rm Ext}:W^{1,n-1}(\partial\Omega)\to
> W^{1,n}(\Omega)$.*

One can conclude this result from a sequence of results in H. Triebel,
*Theory of function spaces.* (Reprint of 1983 edition.) 
Modern Birkhuser Classics. Birkhauser/Springer Basel AG, Basel, 2010 as follows:
using the following results Triebel's book:
Theorem 2.5.6, Theorem 2.7.1, Proposition 2.3.2.2(8), Theorem 2.5.7 
and 2.5.7(9) (in that order) we obtain
the following relations for function spaces on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$:
$$
W^{1,n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})=
H^1_{n-1}=
F^1_{n-1,2}\subset 
F^{1-\frac{1}{n}}_{n,n}=
B^{1-\frac{1}{n}}_{n,n}=
\Lambda^{1-\frac{1}{n}}_{n,n}=
W^{1-\frac{1}{n},n}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1}).
$$
I find this proof highly unsatisfactory.

A self contained and elementary (but difficult) proof can also be found in G. Leoni, 
*A first course in Sobolev spaces.*
Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 105. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2009, see Theorem 14.32, Remark 14.35 and Proposition 14.40.

Comment: For $L^2$ Sobolev spaces, a reasonably elementary Fourier-analytic proof may be found in J.L. Lions and E. Magenes, *Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications, Volume 1* (Springer-Verlag, 1972), see Theorem 9.4, pages 41-43. It is still one of the best expositions on the subject.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Theroem 9.4 is about characterization of traces in terms of fractional Sobolev spaces. $W^{1,n-1}$ is not a fractional Sobolev space and the only question is to show that it embeds to a suitable fractional Sobolev space. Moreover the Theorem 9.4 applies to when $p=2$ only. Note that  here $p-n>2$. Therefore Theorem 9.4 is not relevant here. But thank you for the reference. I will certainly look at it more carefully. Looks like a great book that I wan to add to my library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elementary proof was shown to me by [**Jan Malý**](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/author.html?mrauthid=210365). It has never been published and with his permission we included it in [1] (Proposition 28). The argument is very elementary (1.5 pages with all details), but still too long to be included here.

> **Theorem.** For $n\geq 1$ and $p>1$, there is a bounded linear extension operator $$ E:W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\to W^{1,q}\cap
>  C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}_+), \quad \text{where $q=\frac{(n+1)p}{n}$.}
>  $$ In other words, $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ continuously embeds into
>   the trace space $W^{1-\frac{1}{q},q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ of
>   $W^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}_+)$.

From this result the following corollary follows right away:

> **Corollary.** If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$, is a bounded and smooth domain, then there is a bounded extension operator $$ 
>  E:W^{1,p}(\partial\Omega)\to W^{1,q}\cap C^\infty(\Omega), \quad
>  \text{where $1<p<\infty$ and $q=\frac{np}{n-1}$.} $$

Taking $p=n-1$ and $n>2$ yields the theorem asked in the question. We need to take $n>2$ since for $n=2$ we have $p=n-1=1$ and the result is false in that case (there are counterexamples, see [1]).

**[1] P. Goldstein, P.  Hajłasz,** 
[Jacobians of $W^{1,p}$ homeomorphisms, case $p=[n/2]$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11888). 
 *Calc. Var. Partial Differential Equations* 58 (2019), no. 4, Art. 122, 28 pp.