# Continuous extension of functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f \in W^{1,p} (\partial \Omega)$. Can $f$ be extended to a function $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ such that $u|_{\partial \Omega}=f$ and

$$\lVert u\rVert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}\leq C\lVert f\rVert_{W^{1,p}(\partial \Omega)}?$$

What are the minimal assumptions that guarantee such continuous extensions?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! How do you even define $W^{1,p}(\partial \Omega)$ without any regularity assumptions on $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: Thanks Jochen. We may assume that $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz or even $C^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Theorem.** If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$, is a bounded and smooth domain, then there is a bounded extension operator $$ 
>  E:W^{1,p}(\partial\Omega)\to W^{1,q}\cap C^\infty(\Omega), \quad
>  \text{where $1<p<\infty$ and $q=\frac{np}{n-1}$.} $$

Note that $q>p$ so $W^{1,q}(\Omega)\subset W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Fore more details and link to a proof see: https://mathoverflow.net/a/322635/121665

Comment: I don't see how the corollary follows from the stated theorem:  in:https://mathoverflow.net/a/322635/121665. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on this. Thanks.

Comment: @MathLearner First note that the dimension of the boundary is $n-1$ so you need to replace $n$ by $n-1$ in the theorem and then you get the exponent $q$. Secondly to get boundary of $\Omega$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ you use partition of unity and diffeomrohisms to flatten the boundary. This is a standard technique that you find in any textbook on Sobolev spaces, but there is not enough place to explain it here in details.

Comment: Thank you @Piotr Hajlasz